# Why do columns in data frames change class when subsetted versus apply?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, format, apply

I am trying to add a summary row to a data frame detailing the levels of each column. I ran into a problem applying the levels function across the frame. I think the reason is that columns treated individually are treated as factor vectors, but when the apply function is used they are treated as characters:

```
a = c("a","b","c")
b = c("d","e","f")
m = cbind(a,b)
df = as.data.frame(m)
class(df[,1])
[1] "factor"
apply(df, MARGIN=2, class)
          a           b 
"character" "character"
```

Which I think is the cause of the problem:

```
levels(df[,1])
[1] "a" "b" "c"
apply(df, MARGIN=2, levels)
NULL
```

I had a look at the help documentation on apply, data frames, and around the web. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: This happens because `apply` coerces your data.frame to `matrix` and those can only have one class in all "columns" (since they're just a vector with dimension attribute)

Comment: And from `?matrix`: The default method for ‘as.matrix’ calls ‘as.vector(x)’, and hence e.g. coerces factors to character vectors.

Comment: Apply first checks to see if all the data is numeric. If it is it calls `as.matrix`. If not it calls `as.array`. However, `as.array` then calls `as.vector` which does the conversion that @WeihuangWong indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lapply or sapply function to know your class of variables, to my understanding apply goes through column element wise so each element is a character so the output shows as as character, where as lapply and sapply functions works on variables so it gives class of variables either its as character or factor

```
lapply(df,class)
$a
[1] "factor"

$b
[1] "factor"

sapply(df,class)
       a        b 
"factor" "factor"
```